# freeRADIUS and openLDAP and 802.1X

Tags: centos7, freeradius

I would like to ask a question, that is, I want to build a freeradius server here, and associate it with OpenLDAP for authentication. I have already built the freeradius server here. After testing, freeradius can also communicate with openLDAP data (as shown below)

[image]

But on the wireless AC device, when it passes the pap authentication protocol test, it is normal and can communicate with openLDAP data normally, but if the chap authentication protocol is tested, an error is reported. During the error reporting process, I go to the freeradius server. When entering radiusd -X to view the log, it prompts chap to report an error, as shown in the figure below

[image]

I hope someone can help me solve the problem.

Comment: The error message is clear. What have you done to address that?

Comment: I just don't know how to solve this problem, have you ever encountered this kind of problem here?